# Sorting Drop Down List By Value

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am trying to sort one of my drop down lists by value using jQuery. This is what I have:

```
var optionSelected = $('select option:contains("New York")');
var myParent= optionSelected.parent('select');

myParent.sort(function(x, y){
return $(x).val() < $(y).val() ? -1 : 1;
})
myParent.get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
```

Here I am finding the word `New York`, then finding that parent, which would be the drop down menu. I am then sorting it from 0 - to the highest number, but it is not sorting at all... Am I missing something?

Comment: `myParent` is a jQuery collection containing just a single element, the `<select>` element. It's not an array of the options.

Comment: what is the fix to that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. You need to make a collection of the option elements so you can sort them. And once you do this, you have to put them back into the DOM; sorting the jQuery collection doesn't modify the DOM itself.

```js
$("#sort").click(function() {
  var select = $('select:has(option:contains(New York))');
  var options = select.find("option");
  options.sort(function(x, y) {
    return x.value < y.value ? -1 : 1;
  });
  select.empty().append(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="">Select City</option>
  <option>New York</option>
  <option>London</option>
  <option>Albany</option>
  <option>Paris</option>
</select>
<button id="sort">Sort cities</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting doesn't quite work that way. What you may want to do instead is scrape out the values and put them into an array, then sort the array. For instance:

```js
function doSort() {
  var opts = $('#opts');
  var arr = opts.find('option').map(function(i, el) { 
    return el.value;
  });

  var i, len, opt;

  arr = arr.sort();
  opts.empty().hide();
  for (i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    opt = arr[i];
    opts.append($('<option/>').val(opt).text(opt));
  }
  opts.show();
}

$('#sort').on('click', doSort);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sort">Click to sort</button>
<select id="opts">
  <option value="New York">New York</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
  <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
  <option value="California">California</option>
</select>
```